# How to use popup message on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Can you please tell me what can I use to output a message in wordpress(echo wouldn't work)? I have been using `wp_die( __(……..))` to output a message. But this code will terminate my php code in the worpress page.

```
<?php
  $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
  foreach ($arr as $value) 
  {
      $value = $value * 2;
      //Popup message here indicating the array value ?
  }
?>
```

I am editing the `wp-comments-post.php` file in WordPress. For example, when the user press the "Post Comment" button, above code will run and output the those 4 values in the array.

Comment: What kind of popup? Where is this code happening? A plugin, a template file?

Comment: @brasofilo This code is happening in wp-comments-post.php file. I just want any type of popup message showing the results. Thanks.

Comment: Well, that's what `die()` usually does ... it terminates the running script.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`wp-comment-post.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-comments-post.php) only contains **backend** code. So if you try to echo or output anything in this file, it will appear in the HTML file you call, but it will most likely not be visible to anybody, because it will be overlapped by all the **frontend** elements.

I see two ways, how you could handle this

1. Don't output/echo your desired  information in the `wp-comment-post.php` file, but assign it to any desired variable (in case of your `foreach` loop: assign it to an array element). Then echo it in an appropriate frontend template file, e.g. in the [`comments.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/comments.php) file of your selected theme.
2. Echo your information as a [JavaScript `alert()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+alert+example). This creates a little popup window where you can show your information. Restriction here: The user has to click the popup away, before anything else happens. And as the popup would be invoked in the backend code, the frontend code would be executed *after* the popup has been clicked. Ergo there would be a blank page with the popup, and after clicking it, the rest of the page would be established.